# Find all local extrema

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve an exercise that says:

Find all local extrema of the function:
$$g: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad g(x, y)=3 x^{4}-6 x^{2}-4 y^{3}+2 y^{2}+x y^{2}$$
I know I must solve the equation $\nabla g =(0,0)$. So I write:
$$12x^3-12x+y^2 = 0$$
$$-12y^2+4y+2xy=0$$
and try to solve them simultaneously. But I can't. Actually, I know a solution is (1,0). How can I find out the other solutions?

Comment: @Moo, thank you. But my problem is if substitute $y=x/6+1/3$, how can you find the x? or how can prove it be impossible to find such x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y=0$ the second equation is satisfied, and the first becomes $x^3=x$, so we have the solutions $$(-1,0),(0,0),(1,0)$$

If $y\neq0$ we can divide the second equation through by $y$ to get $$y=\frac{x+2}6\tag1$$  Substituting in the first equation gives $$432x^3+x^2-428x+4=0$$  This is a bit messy.  Let $p(x)=432x^3+x^2-428x+4$.  $p(0)=4>0$ and clearly $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=-\infty$ so $p$ has a negative root.  We find that $$p(.01)=.000432+.0001-4.28+4<0$$ so $p$ has a real root between $0$ and $.01$.  Then the third root must also be real.

Numerical solution gives the roots as $$-1.00575068640708\\0.00926025184743472\\0.994175619744835$$  Then we can use equation $(1)$ to find the $y$ corresponding to each $x$.

This gives $6$ critical points.  They still must be tested to determine whether or not they are local extrema.

The exact values of the roots, computed with sympy, are $$
- \frac{1}{1296} + \frac{\sqrt{554689} \sin{\left(- \frac{\operatorname{arctan}{\left(\frac{46656 \sqrt{78348498}}{10909729} \right)}}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6} \right)}}{648},\\
- \frac{1}{1296} + \frac{\sqrt{554689} \sin{\left(\frac{\operatorname{arctan}{\left(\frac{46656 \sqrt{78348498}}{10909729} \right)}}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6} \right)}}{648},\\
- \frac{\sqrt{554689} \cos{\left(\frac{\operatorname{arctan}{\left(\frac{46656 \sqrt{78348498}}{10909729} \right)}}{3} \right)}}{648} - \frac{1}{1296}
$$
Personally, I find the numerical values far more informative.

Just for the record, here's my python script:

```
from sympy import Symbol, solve, simplify, latex

x = Symbol('x')
p = 432*x**3+x**2-428*x+4
z = solve(p,x)
for r in z:
    r = r.as_real_imag()
    print(latex(simplify(r[0])))
    print(latex(simplify(r[1])))
```

Comment: Is it possible to find the solutions without approximation, for example using the structure of function g to guess the solutions?

Comment: @gb98199 Well, you can use the cubic equation formula to solve for the roots exactly, but it will be even messier.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+432x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-428x%2B4%3D0

Comment: Thanks, yes this is even messier. I was thinking maybe as we can guess the intervals, somehow we can find an easier way for the solution. The problem requires short solution without approximations, which is not possible in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the trigonometric for three real roots ? The solutions would be
$$x_k=\frac{2 \sqrt{554689} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \pi  k-\cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{10909729}{554689 \sqrt{554689}}\right)\right)\right)-1}{1296}$$ with $k=0,1,2$.

Making the values rational to rather high accuracy
$$x_0=\frac{1789}{1808} \qquad x_1=\frac{78}{8345}\qquad x_2=-\frac{1737}{1735}$$
$$y_0=\frac{1849}{3711}\qquad y_1=\frac{2078}{6205}\qquad y_2=\frac{722}{4337}$$
$$g_0=-\frac{6317}{2296}\qquad g_1=\frac{133}{1783}\qquad g_2=-\frac{5177}{1731}$$